# Why isn't Node.js compiled before runtime?

Tags: node.js

My understanding of the technology is that it is compiled on the fly into assembly.  On the speed spectrum it is slower than Java but faster than Ruby and Python.  On the client side an interpreter makes sense but on the server side my first thought is that compilation prior to running, or at least having the option to do so, is an optimal architecture.  If the JavaScript was pre compiled in this way would it run faster than Java? Or is it something to do with weakly typed languages which means that JavaScript will always be slower than Java?

Comment: this will answer your question: http://java.dzone.com/articles/what-javascript-equivalent

Comment: Modern JavaScript interpreters is not really interpreters but adaptive compilers. But dynamic languages is usually slower to execute (because of type-checking) than static languages, so it probably isn't going to be as fast as Java.

Comment: Having static typing (or "strong typing" if it makes you feel good) is one factor that gives some languages a performance improvement, but it's far from the only factor. What I'm saying is that you can't necessarily translate performance in specific benchmarks into a high-level technology choice. For example, I regularly use Grails (JVM), and Express (node.js). I'd be lucky if Grails starts in under 10 seconds, but Express, which offers me comparable functionality, starts in milliseconds.

Comment: @RichardMarr: Exactly. Java has **tons** of overhead for objects and is extremely complex. JavaScript on the other hand is a language with rather simple constructs and very lightweight objects. It may be a lot faster than Java depending on the context.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Some of Node.js is C++ and is pre-compiled.  My understanding though is that there was an effort to keep as much of it in Javascript as possible, but where performance was poor then C++ was used.

Node.js would not be possible without the [V8 JavaScript Engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), which is what compiles the javascript.   This engine is well-known for being extremely fast.  It was built for the Chrome browser, but the performance pays off in Node.js too.

Regarding performance of Node.js, as a web server it is **at least** on a par with the other leading web servers like Apache+PHP.  So performance is not an issue in the common use case.  That said, there are faster technologies.  Erlang based servers are known for being faster under concurrent loads (interestingly, Erlang is also a dynamically typed language).

For pure number crunching cpu/gpu intensive tasks, Node.js is not a good choice, unless you temper it with [Fabric Engine](http://fabric-engine.com/), in which case it can be on a par with C++.

There are a couple of projects that are currently exploring speed issues with JavaScript:

- Dart - http://www.dartlang.org/support/faq.html.  (Its not just about speed but that is part of it).
- Node Native - https://github.com/d5/node.native/